# Proposed Appointment

Tags: hl7-fhir, appointment

I have a simple web based booking journey which allows appointments to be "reserved" before the booking details have been specified (either via login or create new patient). A FHIR based API is going to act as a piece of middleware which sits between the UI and the source booking system.

I'm trying to define a custom FHIR based request message to be able to do this but I'm unsure what can be added to the "actor" as there would be no suitable reference (as it is a required value). Is there a default value which can be specified? Or would the UI just specify an arbitrary value which is echoed back in the response (but ultimately is not saved to the source system)?

Here's the message as an example:

```
{
  "resourceType": "Appointment",
  "status": "proposed",
  "slot": [
    {
      "reference": "Slot/999"
    }
  ],
  "participant": [
    {
    "required": "required",
    "status": "accepted",
      "actor": {
        "reference": "Patient/???",
        "display": "???"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks for any help,

Jose

Answer (score 0):

Who or what are you "reserving"?  That would be the participant that would be specified.  Booking an appointment with *no* participants would mean that no location, provider, or equipment is being reserved - in which case the booking isn't accomplishing much...

Comment: The participant (user) is not known at the point of reservation. The web journey (which cannot be changed) allows a user to hold an appointment while they login / register / pay. The appointment is released after X minutes if it's not booked. This process works fine outside of FHIR - I'm just trying to fit that message structure on top of an existing journey. Thanks Jose

Comment: Lloyd means that the participant list is not limited to just the user. Usually you also add the person, location or device that you make the appointment with in that list. So what/who is the user reserving a booking for? You can add a reference to that, or you can fill in the participant.type field with a role code if you do not have an actual resource to reference. Later, you can also add the user to the participants after they've logged in.